# postgresql prepared statements with JSONB containment

Tags: postgresql-performance, json, jdbc

I'm trying to write a prepared statement using a date held in JSONB.  A prepared statement doesn't allow the containment operator `@>` so I used the function name itself `jsonb_contains` which executes, but now postgres doesn't use the gin index.

Testing in a psql session performance is excellent when I do this

```
select * 
from tab 
where jsonb_obj @> '{"date_el":"2001-01-31"}'
```

because it uses the gin index.  But that won't parse in a prepared statement in java.

When I run this in psql:

```
select * 
from tab 
where jsonb_contains(jsonb_obj->>'date_el', '2001-01-31')
```

performance is very bad.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Java/JDBC certainly allows `@>` to be use in a `PreparedStatement`. What is the error you get?

Comment: Your second query isn't the same as the first. I think you would need to use `jsonb_contains(jsonb_obj, '{"date_el":"2001-01-31"}')`. The second condition would translate to `jsonb_obj -> 'date_el' @> '"2001-01-31"'`

Comment: the error we see is "operator does not exist: jsonb @> text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *the error we see is "operator does not exist: jsonb @> text"*

I assume you are passing the JSON string via `PreparedStatement.setString()`.

Postgres expects a JSONB value, not a text value. You can easily overcome this by casting the parameter to a jsonb:

```
select * 
from tab 
where jsonb_obj @> cast(? as jsonb)
```

Comment: will it use the gin index when using a cast?

Comment: @user172940: yes, because it's  proper `jsonb` value on the right hand side - but the index usage is driven by the expression on the right hand side anyways

Comment: excellent answer, that worked, thank you for your help.